# Is there a tool out there that allows debugging of PHP applications line by line? Like how it's done in perl or .net?

Tags: php, perl, debugging, xdebug

Is there an equivalent of 'perl -d' for PHP? I need to step through some complicated unit test and don't want to install any firefox or client/server extensions. Just looking for a line by line execution of my code.

Thanks

Comment: I use Zendebugger but also curious about if there is a way to do things like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, PHP has no [internal debugger](http://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger-about.php)

There is an [interactive shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php), but not sure if that will be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [VS.php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php), which is a commercial add-in for Microsoft Visual Studio (2003 through 2010). It includes GDB and XDebug and a local Apache server. It supports step-through debugging as you describe and VS integration including the Locals, Watch, and Call Stack windows.

I understand similar systems exist for Eclipse (for free too, presumably) as well as the commercial Komodo IDE.

Answer (score 0):

make use of **Eclipse** and choose perspective as PHP.....you r using APACHE for web server....in that you have to add **XDEBUG** in dll in php **EXT folder** and made some changes in **php.ini** and it will work same as .NET debugger......step by step....